# How can I avoid "Networking Error: Network Failure" when downloading a file from AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am using AWS S3 to access a file in my HTML5 application. Following code works fine on my laptop but it fails on the mobile device (iphone). Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';
 var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'}});
 bucket.getObject({Key: myfile}, function (error, data) {

 if (error != null) {
    alert("Failed to retrieve " + myfile + " :" + error);
 } else {
     //alert("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes");
     localStorage[myfile] = data.Body.toString();
     // do something with data.body

 }});
```

The error I get is:
    "http //local host
    Failed to retrieve foo.json :NetworkingError: Network Failure"

I have the followings CORS configuration for this bucket

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
</CORSRule>
```

Answer (score 34):

I was able to get this resolved by aws tech support. Issue got resolved with the following CORSconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer because it is ;)

Comment: Did this got resolved intermediately after the change, or did it took a while?

Comment: If you're seeing this now, S3 now requires you to write your CORS configuration in JSON. The correct syntax looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842173/in-s3-bucket-cors-configrations-not-allowing-xml-and-asking-for-json-instead