# In S3 Bucket CORS Configrations not allowing xml and asking for json instead

Tags: django, amazon-s3

In S3 Bucket CORS Configrations not allowing "XML" and asking for "Json" instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Was Working earlier but now it is giving me this error "The CORS configuration must be written in valid JSON."
Some Changes are made in "Amazon S3 Bucket" by AMAZON , Please give me json of this to add in CORS ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the new S3 console, the CORS configuration must be JSON. Read more [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html).

In your case, the JSON CORS configuration can be written as follow:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```